# In event-driven architecture, is it ok to have all services send their event to a component that forwards it to the proper service?

Tags: events, service, architecture, event-handling, microservices

Let's say I want to set up and event-driven architecture with services `A`-`D` where the events propagate as follows

```
            A
          /   \
         B     C
              /
             D
```

In other words,

(1) `A` publishes an event

(2) Subscribers `B` and `C` receive `A`'s event

(3) `C` publishes an event

(4) Subscriber `D` receive's `C`'s event

One way is to have services `B` and `C` directly listen to a queue into which `A` posts messages. But the issue I see with this is maintenance. Once the system becomes complicated with 1000s of subscriptions, it becomes difficult to have any visibility into how the updates are propagating.

A solution I propose to this problem is to have another service `X` that knows the tree in the in the first image and is responsible for directing the propagation of events according to the tree. Every service publishes its event to `X` and it publishes the event to the listening services. So it's kinda of a middleman like

```
     A
     |
     X
    / \
   B   C
       |
       X
       |
       D
```

This also makes it easier to track the event propagation.

Are there any downsides to this (other than extra cost associating with twice as much message transferring)?

Answer (score 1):

It is OK but the microservices shouldn't care how they get the messages in the first place. From their point of view the input messages just arrive. You will then be tempted to design your system to depend on some global order of events, which is hard in a distributed scalable system. Resist that temptation and design your system to relay only on local ordering of events (i.e. the ordering in an Event stream emitted by an Aggregate in Event sourcing + DDD).

One downside that I see is that the availability and the scalability may be hurt. You will then have a single point of failure for the entire system. If this fails everything fails. When it needs to be scaled up then you will have again problems as you will have distributed messaging system.

Answer (score 1):

You’re thinking of events like they are implemented in a Winforms UI where the publisher sends the event directly to the subscriber.  That’s not how events work in an EDA architecture.  The word “event” has taken on a whole new meaning.

Before we start, you’re jumbling together the ideas of a message and an event when they really need to be kept separate.  A message is a request for some action to happen, while an event is notification that something has already happened.  The important distinction for this discussion is that a message publisher assumes 1 or more other processes will receive and process the message.  If the message is not processed by something, downstream errors will occur.   An event has no such assumption and can go unread without adversely affecting anything.  Another difference is that once messages are processed they are typically thrown away, whereas events are kept for an extended period (days, or weeks).

With that in mind, the ‘X’ service you talk about already exists (please don’t build one) and is integral to the process – it’s called the bus.  There are 2 types of bus; a message bus (think RabbitMQ, MSMQ, ZeroMQ, etc) or event bus (Kafka, Kinesis, or Azure Event Hub).  In either case, a publisher puts a message on to the bus and subscribers get it from the bus.  You may implement the bus servers as multiple physical buses, but when imagining it think of them all being the same logical bus.

The key point that’s tripping you up, and it’s a subtle difference, is thinking that the message bus has business logic indicating where messages go.  The business logic of who gets what message is determined by the subscribers – the message bus is just a holding place for the messages to wait for pickup.

In your example, A publishes an event to the bus with a message type of “MT1”.  B and C both tell the bus that they are interested in events of type “MT1”.  When the bus receives the request from B and C to be notified of “MT1” messages, the bus creates a queue for B and a queue for C.  When A publishes the message, the bus puts a copy in the “B-MT1” queue and a copy in the “C-MT1” queue.  Note that the bus doesn’t know why B and C want to receive those messages, only that they’ve subscribed.

These messages sit there until processed by their respective subscribers (the processes can poll or the bus can push the messages, but the key idea is that the messages are held until processed).  Once processed, the messages are thrown away.

For C to communicate with D, D will subscribe to messages of type “MT2” and C will publish them to the bus.

Constantin’s answer above has a point that this is a single point of failure, but it can be managed with standard network architecture like failover servers, local message persistence, message acknowledgements, etc.

One of your concerns is that with 1000’s of subscriptions it becomes difficult to follow the path, and you’re right.  This is an inherent downside of EDA and there’s nothing you can do about it.  Eventual consistency is also something the business is going to complain about, but it’s part of the beast and is actually a good thing from a technical perspective because it enables more scalability.  The biggest problem I’ve found using the term Eventual Consistency is that the business thinks it means hours or days, not seconds.

BTW, This whole discussion assumes the message publishers and subscribers are different apps.  All the same ideas can be applied within the same address space, just with a different bus.  If you’re a .net shop look at Mediatr.  For other tech stacks, there are similar solutions that I’m sure google knows about.

Answer (score 1):

If your main concern is visibility into the propagation of events (which is a very valid concern for debugging and long-term application maintenance of a distributed system), you can use a correlation identifier to trace the generation of messages from the initial event through the entire chain. You don't need to build another layer of orchestration -- let your messaging platform handle that for you.

Most messaging platforms/libraries have the concept built in: e.g., NServiceBus defines a [ConversationId](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/headers#messaging-interaction-headers-nservicebus-conversationid) field in the message headers, and AMQP defines a [correlation-id](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#class.basic) field in the basic messaging model.

Your system should have *some* kind of logging that allows you to audit messages -- the correlation ID will allow you to group all messages that result from a single command/request to make debugging distributed logic much simpler.

If you set a GUID in the client requests, you can even correlate actions in the UI to the backend API, right through all the events recursively generated.